# Managing Adobe PDF printer- How to force off the option to rely on system fonts

Tags: pdf, printing, citrix

I am running a Citrix-driven environment, and I have a vital piece of software that creates a PDF repository of all reports as they run. The problem I have is that the users' printers must populate into the environment (Not just the default printers- ALL of them), and a number of the computers have Acrobat 9 or X on them. The software that creates the reports REQUIRES that the Rely On System Fonts is turned off, but some users have it turned on when it comes to the PDF printer on their computers. Sometimes, when user x goes to create a report, it will grab the printer from user y's session that may not have the option properly unset- Then user x's irreplaceable report is lost. The application is a Dexterity application, and I don't have access to the source. Is there a way, in Citrix or in AD, to script this one option to be unset properly? Any idea if there is a registry key or some kind of hook I can activate with a powershell script to fix this headache? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching for weeks to figure this out for myself, and I was looking for one more answer and found your question. To fix your problem I was able to find that the registry key found here:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\DevModePerUser]

Contains all of the current printer properties. If you export it, you can run a script to add the reg key during login. Just make sure that you restart the spooler after words, just to make sure that the changes apply. Also the settings will only apply to the printer with the same name, so you have to have a different reg key for each different printer name, if you have several. I just esported the key after I had changed the printer settings to how I liked them, and then edit the .reg file to remove any data about other installed printers to make sure that the .reg file wouldn't affect any other printers.

Comment: I don't know the exact printer name that will be used, as the computer name is part of the printer name, and whenever someone logs in from a computer with PDF Printer for the first time, I don't usually know the name. I am hoping for a solution that lets me add all printers from a client computer and filter out ones with PDF printer in the name.... Any ideas? Perhaps with a GPO? A GPO would also allow you to add the registry key to avoid an extra script... let me know what you think. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No a GPO wouldn't work because you have to restart the printer spooler in order for the printer to be functional. Plus if you wanted to add specific printers by a process of "filtering" than you would have to use vbs in order to do so. IF it is always an exact printer for an exact user you might be able to use GP in conjunction with having a print server that already has the printer preferences set (Rely On System Fonts off), but still it's easier yet to just set a login script into GP and gives you some more options. But I would have to ask how you know which printer goes where? @user1467163

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this problem is a common problem. Microsoft has acknowledged that the PDF creation issue I am trying to avoid is an issue in GP, starting in (Think it was version) 7. The Microsoft-recommended workaround is to open the PDF Printer properties and uncheck the Use System Fonts box. Adobe does not support this configuration, so they will not provide a clear way to implement it at a network level with clients in many locations and 4 different major versions of Acrobat. The closest I came was a post that identified an incredibly long string I have to hexedit that seems to change in specific minor versions of Acrobat. Way to go M$ and Adobe. So, in other words, no support on major product lines from two major companies. I have nowhere else to go at this point. If anyone else has a solution to this problem, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!